# Layout required in designer but not in hand coded app?

Tags: qt, layout, qt-designer

I'm new to Qt and it's quite a learning curve! 
I've been search/reading/hacking and learning for most of the day on this one.

I'm working on an app that will have a image in a scroll area as it's main purpose. The [image viewer example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-imageviewer-example.html) is where I started. This example appears to be "laid out by hand" if you will - i.e. there are no .ui form files for it (it's trivial so why not).

So here is the rub - I want to use designer to build a much more sophisticated app. If I start fresh with a new project and use designer the resizing doesn't work unless I add layout (used vertical, all appear to fix the resize issue) to the .ui form.

Designer creates a lot more code to do the same thing - I don't care, it is after all an IDE / code generation tool.

However it's not clear to me why the layout is required when I use designer and not if I code it by hand. I searched the code for the image viewer example and there doesn't seem to be ANY layout involved at all, just 3 or 4 nested widgits (Main/Scroll/Label).

Is the default layout basically built in?

Comment: Layouts are used both in the designer and when creating UI imperatively.

Answer (score 1):

The example you linked to uses a `QMainWindow`. This widget has its own layout because it has built-in support for menubars, toolbars, dock widgets and a statusbar:

- [Main Window Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework):

  [image]

Normally, the widget set as the central-widget would need to have a layout *explicitly* set on it in order to layout its own child widgets. However, in your linked example, the central-widget is a `QScrollArea`, which *also* happens to have a built-in layout. This is all just coincidental, though. The large majority of widgets *don't* have a built-in layout, so most GUIs will need to explictly add at least *one* layout, and several will usually be needed for more complex applications.

I would say Qt Designer is absolutely essential when it comes to experimenting with layouts (especially when you start learning Qt). Even if you don't actually use the ui file, it's still very helpful to just view the code that would be generated from it.